# AWS Lambda resetting the whole script after a few API calls

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have deployed an AWS Lambda package which **interprets trading alerts from tradingview.com.**

These alerts are sent to the server at intervals ranging from **subhour to a few hours inbetween.**

I have a **trade log in my application which keeps track of state and other pieces of data.**

This trade log gets **reset after period of time** and i do not know why. My guess is that this happens because the whole script gets reset.

Why is this happening?

Comment: What do you mean that you keep log in your app? Where do you keep it? Inside a lambda function between different executions, e.g. in its `/tmp` storage?

Comment: no it is not in `/tmp` storage. I have it in a class wrapper within my app.py file.

Comment: Lambda storage is not permanent. So after few executions, you can get new, clean environment, will all global variables and local state cleared. You have to keep persistent data outside of lambda, e.g. in DynamoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lambda function runs in a **temporary** environment when its [invoked](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html):

> When a Lambda function is invoked, AWS Lambda launches an execution context based on the configuration settings you provide. The execution context is a **temporary runtime environment** that initializes any external dependencies of your Lambda function code, such as database connections or HTTP endpoints.

What's more, the lambda will keep your temporary environment for some time. It is often not reset after each invitation:

> After a Lambda function is executed, AWS Lambda **maintains the execution context for some time** in anticipation of another Lambda function invocation.

Most importantly,you can't rely on it for keeping persistent data between invocation:

> When you write your Lambda function code, **do not assume that AWS Lambda automatically reuses the execution context** for subsequent function invocations.

For persistent storage of data, such as your trade logs, you have to use **external data store**. Often, for this DynamoDB is used, but can be ElastiCache, RDS, S3 and more.